# Registering Event Handlers

Tags: javascript

When I try to register event handlers on children elements of a particular element, I usually register the handler on the parent element and I let that handle the event invocation (event bubbling). Some code to make it clear:

```
<div id="news">
        <p class="list"><a href="#">A</a></p>
    <p class="list"><a href="#">B</a></p>
    <p class="list"><a href="#">C</a></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var thisValue = e.originalTarget;

    //The value of 'this' in a handler function is the DOM element on 
    //which the handler was defined on
    //e.originalTarget returns the original DOM element the event occurs on before 
    //it bubbled all the way up the DOM tree.
}

var elt = document.getElementById('news');
elt.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
```

This is the method I know and I use frequently. However, while reading an article on the web today I came across another method.

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  //some code here
}

var lists = document.querySelectorAll('#news .list'); //returns a NodeList object (array-like object)
[].forEach.call(lists, function(list) {
  list.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
});
```

Which method do you think is more efficient in registering event handlers? Registering the handler function on a parent element and handle the event with bubbling or the latter method?

Comment: Related; here's a jQuery explanation of direct vs delegated events that may answer your question: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events